# Every seconds: measurement: 6 plots, which ones to update?

Tags: algorithm

The system shall accept one measurement every second. The system shall present 6 real-time plots:

- last minute
- last hour
- last day
- last week
- last month
- last year.

For example, here is a beautiful yearly plot of the measurement presenting the average temperature for every month of the year(suppose the plot consists of 12 datapoints, connected with straight lines). When and how should I update it? The worst case is to re-calcucate the average temperature for each month at every measurement (once per second), then redraw the plot.

[image]

The plot of last minute we solve with a circular buffer - the new measurement is simply pushed to the deque eveyr second.

What about the other plots? How do we minimize the re-calculations for each one?

---

## Solution

Keep averages of all vectors. Whe a new event happens, check which vectors to update (time % vector_sample_period). For the chosen vectors, ask the previous vector for it's average and push it in own circular buffer.

Comment: What calculations? There's not enough information here to answer anything. Please post the code you currently have, and some data so we can see what is required.

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: @ Mike W, This is a hobby project. The plots consist of averages over the last minute. hour, etc. **How do I avoid re-calculating the average of all measurements over the last year, every second?**

Comment: I think I understood your problem and have a simple and elegant solution. To have this question reopened, though, you still need to rephrase your need to be more clear for others. Try adding a simple example with numbers.

Comment: @Slanec, please feel free to improve my question. I can't seem to look at it from a different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You minimize re-calculation by calculating only when needed. For example when you start over on the circular buffers.